# The strategy in calculating models in z3py

Tags: z3py

I just wonder what the strategy is in calculating a model in z3py. Or is it different in general checking and fixed point.

Well, usually we used a tricky to pick up a solution from a model and add it back as constraint to find another model, until we meet unsat. This is very handy when deal with a simple case.

However, when I adopted this approach again in find all models in fixed point (Horn Logic). I met the problem of efficiency. That is, it is reasonable quick to find the first model, then I run the second round by adding the found model as a constraint. Well, it took a little bit longer to find the second one. But when repeating it again and again, it took longer and longer to find next one.

I know z3 builds a big HashTable to find a model. If z3 uses a same HashTable and continues to search from the last location where the last model is found, it should take less time because the searching space is smaller.

So, what is the real strategy in z3py when dealing with this issue?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled about the fact, that future runs are slower than previous ones. With warm-starting, would not expect this (i have not experiece with z3, but enough with SAT & MIP). All model-counting approaches other that the naive one you described will use some additional information about your problem, so there will be advantages using a tailored one. There are some general approaches regarding approximation like [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/selman/papers/pdf/05.sat.new-approach-model-counting.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. That's the reason why I asked the question and I'd like to know the strategy in z3. I suppose  when we put more constraints, we can find a model quicker. But the fact is not.